# Can one see Redeemer value on Blockchain?

Tags: redeemer, blockchain-explorer

Redeem value is never revealed anywhere right? i mean on the BlockChain explorer i cant see someone's redeem passed?
It it sent to Validator to validate and that's it.

Comment: which explorer are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The redeemer is stored in the transaction, so is visible onchain.
[CardanoScan.io](https://cardanoscan.io) is one example of a blockchain explorer that displays the redeemer value for transactions that execute a plutus script (contract).